# SSL Error:“unsupported certificate purpose” for HAProxy's client

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy, client-certificates

I'm trying to set up client certificate authentication using HAProxy.

With OpenSSL, I have created a certificate chain as (**CA cert --> Intermediate cert --> Server Cert**) and After signing Intermediate with CA key and server cert with Intermediate key, I concat then in a sequence of (**server-cert.pem + Intermediate-cert.pem + Root-cert.pem + Server-key.pem**)

```
[root@ip-172-31-0-168 /]# cd /etc/ssl/CertChain
[root@ip-172-31-0-168 CertChain]# ls -la
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  265 Jul 15 14:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root   86 Jul 15 13:29 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2114 Jul 15 13:34 ca-cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17 Jul 15 13:53 ca-cert.srl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3268 Jul 15 13:34 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9374 Jul 15 14:39 haproxySSLFile.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2000 Jul 15 13:53 Intermidate-cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17 Jul 15 14:01 Intermidate-cert.srl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3272 Jul 15 13:51 Intermidate-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1781 Jul 15 13:51 Intermidate-req.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1988 Jul 15 14:01 server-cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3272 Jul 15 13:56 server-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1769 Jul 15 13:56 server-req.pem
```

The highlighted file is the concatenated version of certificates, the location of the file I have placed within the HAProxy config file.

Once Haproxy is up and running I download CA-Cert.pem file from ssl cert directories and to test ssl encryption I choose postman(Client) where I upload that CA-Cert.pem file.

```
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/CertChain/haproxySSLFile.pem
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    mode http
    default_backend apps
```

After Running this through postman(Client), I'm getting ( **SSL Error: Unsupported certificate purpose**)

```
Certificate purposes:
SSL client : Yes
SSL client CA : No
SSL server : Yes
SSL server CA : No
Netscape SSL server : Yes
Netscape SSL server CA : No
S/MIME signing : Yes
S/MIME signing CA : No
S/MIME encryption : Yes
S/MIME encryption CA : No
CRL signing : Yes
CRL signing CA : No
Any Purpose : Yes
Any Purpose CA : Yes
OCSP helper : Yes
OCSP helper CA : No
Time Stamp signing : No
Time Stamp signing CA : No
```

Above is the list of certificate purposes, that is already defined. I'm not able to figure out what should be the specific purposes I need to specify as my goal is to encrypt/decrypt the incoming traffic through SSL for Haproxy.

[Postman(Client) Error Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRhfy.png)

I've spent many hours attempting to figure out what the issue is, but I'm no closer.
So I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Unsupported certificate purpose means that the purpose of the certificate is not suitable for what you are using it for. There are specific and distinct purposes for server certificate  client certificate and probably any of these are missing. More can be said if a) the content of the certificates is known or the __exact__ (reproducible) procedure you created these and b) you make clear where exactly you get this error (client or server). Also, you write about client authentication but I don't see anything like this done.

Comment: I'm trying to establish an SSL connection between HAProxy (Server) and Postman (Client). So, when I try to test this SSL by putting the CA-Cert.pem file into Postman, then I'm experiencing a certificate unsupported purpose error.
So bottom line ---
When I calling a server from a client at that moment I'm facing (unsupported purpose error).

Comment: Thanks for the added details. Please make sure that the intermediate certificate also has SSL server as purpose.

Comment: The certificate purpose of intermediate and server certs is defined as (Any Purpose: Yes), however, I'm having trouble figuring out if this is the correct purpose.

Comment: @vivekchoudhary did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew , Not yet, Still exploring. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated